# convert JS var to PHP and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php

Here I am getting values from `textarea` in array variable.

After that I convert javascript variable to PHP variable and perform some processing over it.

After process completed again I convert `PHP to JS` and alert. But when I alert, it gives empty result.

```
<script>
    $( "#convert" ).click(function() {
        var arabic = document.getElementById("ar").value; // ar is id of text area          
        <?php $ar_terms = "<script>document.write(arabic)</script>"?>           
        <?php
        $string=implode(",",$ar_terms);    
        $result = array();    
        foreach ($ar_terms as $term) {             
           // echo $Arabic->ar2en($term);    
            array_push($result, $Arabic->ar2en($term));                    
        }    
        $result=implode(",",$result);
        ?>
        var arabic = new Array();
        arabic='<?php echo $result; ?>';
        alert(arabic);
    });
</script>
```

Entire code is here : https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/d4ac41fa864fd8ae0521

Comment: php happens serverside, before the page is even loaded. javascript happens after the page is loaded. You are trying to access a value with PHP that doesn't exist when the code is run.

Comment: @serakfalcon: I checked few SO threads where such conversion was asked. Does this short of processing is not possible?

Comment: normally, you'd use AJAX: javascript would send a request to the server, and the server would respond with information it can use.

Comment: What is `ar2en`? That isn't a native PHP function. Is that part of an external class?

Comment: You can not convert js var to PHP because php is serverside and js client, however can you add your code

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't think it's relevant, the problem seems to be that the OP is trying to pass the variable `arabic` from js to php

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes, but I included necessary files `require '../../Arabic.php';` here is complete code https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/d4ac41fa864fd8ae0521

Comment: Far as I know, least in PHP is that, variables can't be processed/echo'ed properly inside single quotes. Whether this is the case inside JS, and that you can change `arabic='<?php echo $result; ?>';` to `arabic="<?php echo $result; ?>";` yet am not 100% that would make a difference, but do try it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks but no luck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing in this scenario to pass the variable from PHP to js. You can convert the array using json_encode() before echoing:

```
    $result=json_encode( implode(",",$result) );
```

As a result, when you assign this variable to js in the `<?= ?>` block, it will read the json string and thus the array will be assigned:

```
    arabic='<?php echo $result; ?>';
```

Comment: OK. If you already have the array, then don't implode() it. Just do $result = json_encode( $result );

Comment: That means your $result is empty. Which makes me think that $ar_terms must be empty too. To verify, just place <?= var_dump($ar_terms)?> below the assignment line.

Comment: thanks, there is some issue I could not find, tried it in another way which works but having different issue pelase see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544576/response-from-php-script-disappears-after-jquery-button-click-event